# Convert complex JOIN query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter-2

I'm converting my existing website to CI, and I have been trying for several days to convert this query to CI-friendly code:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT t1.mnumber, t1.mcontent, t1.mcontact
    FROM sms t1
    JOIN (
        SELECT mContent,mcontact, mnumber, MAX(mID) mID
        FROM sms
        GROUP BY mContact
    ) t2 ON t1.mcontact = t2.mcontact AND t1.mid = t2.mid
    GROUP BY t1.mContact
    ORDER BY t1.mid DESC
");
```

But no matter what I try, I can't get the correct result on CI.

I hope you guys can help me out here!

---

The closest to a result that i did get, was when i used the subquery hack. 
However, out of frustration i deleted the block of code and kept trying.

I decided to use a flat query, like the one posted above. This almost gives me results.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT t1.mnumber, t1.mcontent, t1.mcontact FROM sms t1
JOIN (SELECT mContent,mcontact, mnumber, MAX(mID) mID FROM sms GROUP BY mContact) t2
ON t1.mcontact = t2.mcontact AND t1.mid = t2.mid GROUP BY t1.mContact ORDER BY t1.mid DESC"); 


$contacts = array();

//Add data to our array
foreach($query->result() as $row){
     echo $row->mNumber;
}

return $contacts;
```

However, in my view i get the notice "Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$mNumber"

So still no results, plus i prefer the CI query method.

Comment: Please can you show what you have tried so far? You say you have been trying for several days so no need to show everything, you can just show the closest you have come to the result you want :-)

Comment: Thank you for formatting my post a bit DaveRandom :)

Comment: My advice: **don't**. You have a query written that works. It's built specifically for a certain type of database, so you don't need the query builder's DB-agnostic capabilities. All you're doing is making more work for yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use it in codeigniter like this

```
$query = "  SELECT t1.mnumber, t1.mcontent, t1.mcontact
            FROM sms t1
            JOIN (
                SELECT mContent,mcontact, mnumber, MAX(mID) mID
                FROM sms
                GROUP BY mContact
            ) t2 ON t1.mcontact = t2.mcontact AND t1.mid = t2.mid
            GROUP BY t1.mContact
            ORDER BY t1.mid DESC"; 
$result =   $this->db->query($query);           
return $result->result();
```

2nd Method

You can use sub query way of codeigniter to do this for this purpose you 
will have to hack codeigniter. like this. Go to system/database/DB_active_rec.php 
Remove public or protected keyword from these functions

```
public function _compile_select($select_override = FALSE)
public function _reset_select()
```

Now subquery writing in available And now here is your query with active record

```
$select =   array(
                'mContent',
                'mcontact',
                'mnumber',
                'MAX(mID) mID'
            );
$this->db->select($select);
$this->db->from('sms');
$this->db->group_by('mContact');
$subquery = $this->db->_compile_select(); // get the query string

$this->db->_reset_select(); // reset so it can newly form the query

unset($select);
$select =   array(
                't1.mnumber',
                't1.mcontent',
                't1.mcontact'
            );
$this->db->select($select);
$this->db->join('',"($subquery)");
$this->db->from('sms t1');
$this->db->group_by('t1.mContact');
$this->db->order_by('t1.mid','DESC');
$result =   $this->db->get();
return $result->result();
```

And the thing is done. Cheers!!!
Note : While using sub queries you must use

```
$this->db->from('myTable')
```

instead of

```
$this->db->get('myTable')
```

which runs the query.

Comment: I tried your solution. With solution 1, i get undefined index error. However, if i change my query to 'SELECT * FROM SMS', your solution works perfectly. Second solution, i get an SQL error. So still no luck :(

Comment: Problem solved, i needed to name my fields "AS" in order to pass them to the view. THANKS!!

Comment: I got Fatal error: Call to protected method CI_DB_active_record::_compile_select()

Comment: @itskawsar you may be using the new version or you might not have removed public or protected keywords.Read the answer carefully again and follow.

Comment: i am having problem with function _compile_select();
with your solution i am able to get the result.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Er, shouldn't that be (at a guess)...

```
 SELECT t1.mnumber
      , t1.mcontent
      , t1.mcontact
      , t1.mid
   FROM sms t1
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT mcontact
             , MAX(mID) mID 
          FROM sms 
         GROUP BY mContact
      ) t2
     ON t1.mcontact = t2.mcontact 
    AND t1.mid = t2.mid 
  ORDER 
     BY t1.mid DESC;
```

Comment: Just need to poor that into an CI active query. It keeps outputting errors

Answer (score 0):

This may not fully answer your question, but for those of you who are Googling for a `"JOIN AND"` (so that you can `AND` some extra stuff on the `Join`, *before* the `WHERE` clause kicks in), here's a hacky way to do it:

```
$this->db->join('table_to_join', 'first_table.connect_id = table_to_join.id AND table_to_join.some_filter != 0');
```

Definitely not pretty, but that obviously forces the `AND` to occur immediately after the `JOIN`, before you get into the `WHERE` stuff for the rest of your query on `first_table`

Answer (score 0):

Well, its easy to implement in CI version 3+

```
$subQuery = $this->db->select( 'table2.*' )
  ->join( 'table3', 'table3.orderId = table2.fkOrderId', 'INNER' )
  ->where()->get_compiled_select( 'table2' );

$this->db->select( 'table1.*' )
  ->join( '(' . $subQuery . ') AS b', 'b.`fkCouponId` = table1.couponId', 'LEFT', FALSE )
  ->get( 'table1' )
```

**TIP:** Make sure you don't use any query builder methods above the subquery part.